# WCF Service Returning Object with no properties

Tags: database, vb.net, wcf, web-services, microsoft-metro

I'm learning how to access data on a DB using a WCF web service. My main issue I've run into is that when making a call for the result from the service, the return value is of type UniversityClass but no properties are available and I believe its real type is simply an object, therefore I have no access to any of its 'real' properties.

Heres a snippet of the class in my interface called 'Service1'

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IService1

    <OperationContract()>
    Function GetUniversity(ByVal universityID As Integer) As UniversityClass

End Interface

<DataContract()>
Public Class UniversityClass

    Private _universityId As Integer

    Public Property UniversityID As Integer
        Get
            Return _universityId
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _universityId = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

and heres a preview of me making the call to the service to get the data

```
    Dim client As New ServiceReference1.Service1Client
        Dim result As New ServiceReference1.UniversityClass

        Dim x = client.GetUniversityAsync(Integer.Parse(tbUniversityID.Text))
        Dim r As WCFServiceExample.ServiceReference1.UniversityClass = Await x
        If x.IsCompleted Then
            result = x.Result
        End If

        tbResult.Text = result. _ _ _ _

'// ^ No properties accessible here even though it recognizes that result is of type UniversityClass
```

Upon inspecting ServiceReference1.UniversityClass I get taken to Referece.vb and notice that there is Partial Class UniversityClass which inherits object. I think perhaps that may be the reason why I don't have any access to the properties defined in my Service1 class because it thinks UniversityClass is an object with no type.

I've tried rebuilding all projects individually, rebuilding the solution and still nothing.

Would love some assistance with how to actually get an object of type UniversityClass to return from my service.

Recognizes the type: http://i50.tinypic.com/e5mhvk.jpg
No properties available: http://i50.tinypic.com/wmjui9.jpg

Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client can't see the UniversityID because you haven't marked it as a data member:

```
<DataContract()>
Public Class UniversityClass

    Private _universityId As Integer

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property UniversityID As Integer
        Get
            Return _universityId
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _universityId = value
        End Set
    End Property
```